# SQL max value form count()

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I've got a following query:

```
SELECT BusID, count(BusID) as 'NoofConnections'
FROM mytable
Group By BusID
Order by BusID
```

And I get following table:

```
BusID   NoofConnections
=========================
1       6
2       6
4       3
5       2
3       1
```

And I will to select just maximum from NoofConnections, so in this case LIMIT 1 doesn't work, so we have two equal values. Like this:

```
 BusID   NoofConnections
=========================
1            6
2            6
```

Any ideeas?

Comment: do you want to select maximum value for each busid ? share your expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT BusID, COUNT(*) as NoofConnections
FROM mytable
GROUP BY BusID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM mytable
                   GROUP BY BusID
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  )
ORDER BY BusID;
```

Comment: i tryed this with sum instead of count, but it doesnt work, is it possible to do the same thing but with sum?

Comment: @kasia . . . There is no `SUM()` in this answer, so I have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: I guess OP mean use `SUM()` *instead* of `COUNT()`.  First you need to replace the `*` for the field you want to sum, as long as the field is numeric then replacing all the `COUNT` for `SUM` should work. Anyway instead of say `doesnt work` you should tell us what is wrong so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subselect

```
  select * from (
    SELECT BusID, count(BusID) as NoofConnections
    FROM mytable
    Group By BusID

  )  t1 
  where t1.NoofConnections = (  select max(NoofConnections)
      from (
      SELECT BusID, count(BusID) as NoofConnections
      FROM mytable
      Group By BusID
      )
```